# linking a shared library against a shared library

Tags: linker, shared-libraries

I have problems using a shared library that was linked against a shared library. I will show you a minimal example of my problem.

Suppose, I have `A.c` and `A.h` and want to generate `libA.so` like this:

A.h

```
double test(void);
```

A.c

```
#include "A.h"

double test(void) {
    return 2.0;
}
```

Compilation: `gcc -shared -o libA.so A.c -fPIC`

Now I want to build a shared library `libB.so` that uses the function `test()` from `libA.so`:

B.c

```
#include "A.h"

double test123(void) {
    return test();
}
```

Compilation: `gcc -shared -o libB.so B.c -fPIC -L. -lA`

Both compilations work perfectly. `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ldd libB.so` shows `libA.so => ./libA.so (0xb7778000)` so I assume, that `libB.so` knows it was linked against `libA.so` and knows where to look for it. (I wonder why I need LD_LIBRARY_PATH here...)
However, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. nm libB.so | c++filt` shows `U test`, saying that the symbol `test` is undefined.

How come? What did I do wrong? Why can the functions of `libA.so` not be found in `libB.so`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why can the functions of libA.so not be found in libB.so

Because `libA.so` and `libB.so` are not the same file.

The outcome you observed is exactly the *correct* and the *desired* one.

IF you want `test()` to be in `libB.so`, then you have to *put it there*. If you want it to come from `libA.so`, then you have already achieved this.